# Error with Bit Shifting in C while Accessing Odd Index of Array

Tags: c, bluetooth-lowenergy, bit-shift

I am currently sending an array of unsigned, 8 bit integers to a C program through Bluetooth (as a characteristic). When this packet is received, I want to take a pair of the indexes and "concatenate" their numbers, like so:

```
Input: [0xDE, 0xAD, 
        0xDE, 0xAD, 
        0xBE, 0xEF]

Output: [0xDEAD, 0xDEAD, 0xBEEF]
```

However, I am running into a strange issue. My code works fine when I output to an even index (Taking the first two elements of the array and concatinating them), but fails when I output to an odd element (For example, trying to concatinate elements 3 and 4 (0xDE and 0xAD).

So, my output that I am getting from the program is this:

```
Input: [0xDE, 0xAD, 
        0xDE, 0xAD, 
        0xBE, 0xEF]

Output: [0xDEAD, 0xADDE, 0xBEEF]
```

Here is my code:

```
  for(int i = 0; i < numUUID; i++)
  {
      // The i+1 and i+2 are because the first value of the array contains
      // a byte on how many UUIDs are incoming
      uuidFilter[i] = (incoming[i + 1] << 8) | incoming[i + 2];
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the output you're seeing? I would expect this to output `[0xDEAD, 0xADDE, 0xDEAD]`

Comment: Replace `i++` with `i+=2`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your input is like this:

```
[numUUID, 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF]
```

your high bytes are at indices 1, 3, and 5 while low bytes are at indices 2, 4, and 6. Notice that they go by twos. That means that when you index into the array you should have a `2*i` somewhere, so that you step by two on each increment. Here's the answer:

```
for(int i = 0; i < numUUID; i++)
{
    uuidFilter[i] = (incoming[2*i + 1] << 8) | incoming[2*i + 2];
}
```

This is assuming that `numUUID` is the number of **pairs** that you are concatenating. If it's the number of bytes, then of course you need to divide that by two in the loop condition.

Comment: OP didn't make it clear what `numUUID` meant. I added my assumption to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're processing 2 elements from the incoming array but only incrementing `i` by 1. So you're processing
`incoming[i_1] and incoming[i_2]`
`incoming[i_2] and incoming[i_3]`

but it looks like you should be incrementing `i` by 2  which would give you
`incoming[i_1] and incoming[i_2]`
`incoming[i_3] and incoming[i_4]`

You'd also have to start your loop at i=1 to skip the first byte.